# Looking for any way to emulate Bluetooth A2DP connection via Android application

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I'm exploring the feasibility of developing an Android solution to emulate Bluetooth A2DP headphones, with the goal of using another Android device in this role. I've investigated the Android Bluetooth API and looked into A2DP profiles, but I'm uncertain about the feasibility of emulating A2DP headphones.

Is this possible, and what limitations might be encountered in Android for implementing such a solution? Any insights or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.